# Wrap up the returned data by TypeVar

Tags: python, fastapi

Base on FastAPI.
My return data schemas is

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    fname: str
    items: list[Item]
```

I want to wrap up the returned data.Like this

```json
{
  "code": 1,
  "msg": "string",
  "data": {
    "id": 0,
    "fname": "string",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "user_id": 0,
        "name": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I have two questions.

1. In OpenAPI,no schemas for data.

```json
{
  "code": 1,
  "msg": "string",
  "data": "string"
}
```

2. When I get user,Items are not displayed

My code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from fastapi import Depends,FastAPI
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import sqlalchemy as sa
Base = declarative_base()
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session, relationship


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./sql_app.db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


def get_session():
    session = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        session.close()


class DbUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    fname = sa.Column(sa.String(100), nullable=False)
    items = relationship("DbItem")


class DbItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), sa.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(100), nullable=False)


app = FastAPI()
T = TypeVar('T')


class DbWrapper(object):
    code: int = 1
    msg: str = None
    data = None

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


class ApiWrapper(BaseModel, Generic[T]):
    code: int = 1
    msg: str = None
    data: T

    # def __init__(self, data: T):
    #     self.data = data

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class Item(BaseModel):
    id: int
    user_id: int
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    class Meta:
        orm_model = DbItem


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    fname: str
    items: list[Item]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


class UserWrapper(ApiWrapper):
    data: User


@app.get("/users/{id}", response_model=ApiWrapper[User])
def get_user(id: int, session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    db_user = session.query(DbUser).get(id)
    return DbWrapper(db_user)


@app.post("/users/")
def add_user(user: User, session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    parsed_schema = parse_pydantic_schema(user)
    session.add(DbUser(**parsed_schema))
    session.commit()
    return {"code": 1}


@app.get("/users/", response_model=list[User])
def list_user( session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    db_users = session.query(DbUser).all()
    return db_users

def is_pydantic(obj: object):
    """Checks whether an object is pydantic."""
    return type(obj).__class__.__name__ == "ModelMetaclass"


def parse_pydantic_schema(schema):
    """
        Iterates through pydantic schema and parses nested schemas
        to a dictionary containing SQLAlchemy models.
        Only works if nested schemas have specified the Meta.orm_model.
    """
    parsed_schema = dict(schema)
    for key, value in parsed_schema.items():
        try:
            if isinstance(value, list) and len(value):
                if is_pydantic(value[0]):
                    parsed_schema[key] = [schema.Meta.orm_model(**schema.dict()) for schema in value]
            else:
                if is_pydantic(value):
                    parsed_schema[key] = value.Meta.orm_model(**value.dict())
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError("Found nested Pydantic model but Meta.orm_model was not specified.")
    return parsed_schema
```

When I change `@app.get("/users/{id}", response_model=ApiWrapper[User])` to `@app.get("/users/{id}", response_model=UserWrapper)`,everything is OK.
I have many classes, so I want to use `ApiWrapper[User]`.Then I met the two questions mentioned above.